# Create object from JSON schema

Tags: python

I have the following JSON schema:

```json
schema = '''{
    "title": "Example Schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "firstName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "lastName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "age": {
            "description": "Age in years",
            "type": "integer",
            "minimum": 0
        },
        "dogs": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {"type": "string"},
            "maxItems": 4
        },
        "gender": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": ["male", "female"]
        },
        "deceased": {
            "enum": ["yes", "no", 1, 0, "true", "false"]
            }
    },
    "required": ["firstName", "lastName"]
} '''
```

What is the best way to create object from this schema using `Python3`?
Currently I'm using https://pypi.org/project/python-jsonschema-objects/ but wonder if there is better way to do that

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to be able to convert to a simple class like structure or the ability to use "dot" notation you could use `types.SimpleNamespace`.

You can use this as a very simple example:

```
import json
from types import SimpleNamespace

def load_schema(schema):
    def from_dict(data):
        return SimpleNamespace(**{
            k: v if not isinstance(v, dict) else from_dict(v)
            for k, v 
            in data.items()
        })
    return from_dict(json.loads(schema))
    
print(load_schema(schema))
```

---

```
namespace(
    title='Example Schema',
    type='object'
    properties=namespace(
        firstName=namespace(type='string'),
        lastName=namespace(type='string')),
        age=namespace(
            description='Age in years',
            type='integer'
            minimum=0,
        ), 
        dogs=namespace(
            items=namespace(type='string'),
            maxItems=4, type='array'
        ),
        gender=namespace(
            enum=['male', 'female'],
            type='string'
        ),
        deceased=namespace(enum=['yes', 'no', 1, 0, 'true', 'false']),
    required=['firstName', 'lastName'],
)
```

---

```
>>> cls = load_schema(schema)
>>> cls.age.minimum
0
```

Answer (score -1):

Simpy use the inbuild `json` package and it's string loading function [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads).

```
import json

schema = ''' ... '''

obj = json.loads(schema)
```